# How can i define a NavigationController that embeds a ViewController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have seen a project with the following storyboard:

http://www.disclafani.org/vc.png

I would like to know how it has been built the CustomerPagesViewController as NavigationController, i don't see a RootNavigationController for it.

In short terms ... how can i define a UINavigationController that embeds a ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag and drop a navigation controller in storyboard, it will create two controllers (two scenes to be more precise): a `navigationbar controller` and a `tableview controller` that will be defined as your `rootview controller`. All you have to do is replace your tableview controller by your custom controller: it will be embedded in your navigation controller.

**EDIT**
Sorry I think i mislead you in my first answer: it doesn't look like you can simply replace one controller by another. If you want a custom view controller embedded in a navigation controller a better approach would be:

1. Drag and drop a **`view controller`** on storyboard
2. Reference your **`custom view controller`** by editing the custom class field in the identity inspector
3. Drag and drop a navigation controller on storyboard
4. select your custom view controller and select from editor the **`embed in`** option by choosing navigation controller: your navigation controller should now contains your view controller. You can deleted the tableview controller that was created when you drag and drop the navigation bar controller.

Comment: It's ok for the first navigation controller, but in the image i see a second controller on the right that has not a bound navcontroller... How can it be built?

Comment: which second controller are u referring here the one on your pic?

Comment: CustomerPagesViewController ; it is a navigationcontroller but really don't know how it has been created

Comment: The name reflected is just the name of a customViewController (this has been set-up in the identity inspector under custom class in IB)